# Using Taxee.io API

Tags: express, curl, http-post

I'm trying to access the Taxee.io API using the request npm module. The documentation is slightly poor and the difference between the Mashape info and the website's info is confusing.

https://taxee.io/

The docs have one example of a request here.

`curl 'https://taxee.io/api/v2/calculate/2017' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJBUElfS0VZX01BTkFHRVIiLCJodHRwOi8vdGF4ZWUuaW8vdXNlcl9pZCI6IjU4NDQ4MTA4Mzg2NjhhMTU4ZDU0ZmIzNSIsImh0dHA6Ly90YXhlZS5pby9zY29wZXMiOlsiYXBpIl0sImlhdCI6MTQ5OTA1MzU0NX0.pOwC5JEC7trLaaZVgHHGu_rvN0-EGa3RMm8BgJ-M9gk' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'state=NC&filing_status=married&pay_periods=26&pay_rate=116500&exemptions=2'`

I however want to use the request npm module and am struggling to bridge the gap in how it will work in my express app.

```
const request = require('request');

request.post('https://taxee.io/api/v2/calculate/2017', {
  'auth': {
    'Bearer': 'mykey'
  }
});
```

This is what I have thus far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The response I get back is no auth mechanism defined

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that properties are case sensitive in JavaScript. You must pass the bearer token under the key `bearer` and not `Bearer`.

To replicate the `Content-type` and pass data, use the [form support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication) of the library.

E.g. like this:

```
{
    auth: {
        bearer: '<token>',
    },
    form: {
        state: 'NC',
        // ...
    },
}
```

Comment: Meshing a form https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp with my request has been the next challenge